# Refresh ComboBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

I've tried to make the `ComboBox` refresh itself after I click the delete button, but when I try this it gives me the error:

> Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

This is the code from the `Delete` button:

```
private void deleteBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   con.Open();
   string Query = "DROP TABLE [" + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "]";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);

   SqlDataReader myReader;

   try
   {          
      myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      MessageBox.Show("Deleted");

      this.comboBox1.Items.Remove(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }

   con.Close();    
}
```

And this is the code from the `ComboBox`:

```
try
{
   con.Open();

   SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

   sqlCmd.Connection = con;
   sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables";

   SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);        

   DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
   sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
   comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
   comboBox1.DisplayMember = "table_name";
   comboBox1.ValueMember = "table_name";

   con.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the DataSource-Property automatically pairs the ComboBox to the database table and prevents you from manually modifying just the GUI-element.

To force a refresh of the ComboBox (although you might not need to, seeing how the Form should handle it) try this:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = null;
comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

The error message tells you, that you have set the [`DataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x8160f6f(v=VS.110).aspx) property on "comboBox1". So, you should remove the `DataSource`:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = null;
```

Or if you want to keep the `DataSource`, don't try to remove items by yourself (you should do it in your dataSource table, not in comboBox items)

Answer (score 1):

As I understood there a list of tables on your ComboBox and you want to Drop the selected item:

1st thing: if you work with DDL queries (as DROP,CREATE,ALTER..) and some of DML queries (as DELETE,Update,INSERT..) you should use the method `ExecuteNonQuery` not the `ExecuteReader` method as you did 
2nd : make sure that the property `AutoPostBack` on the ComboBox Control is set to true

Answer (score 0):

To force a refresh of the ComboBox (although you might not need to, seeing how the Form should handle it) try this:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```